# How to enable user to send bug report and log in android app through email?

Tags: android, email, logging

I am a newbie in Android, currently developing an app with some others. Right now the app is quite unstable and I want to add a bug report feature.

I have seen something in ios that a user press the screen with two fingers and it will pop up options to send bug report or UI report.

What I want to do in Android:

1. through a gesture to enable a user to send screentshot and log through email.
2. It will pop up a menu to ask the user which email app he would like to use and then direct the user to that certain app. (the email apps need to be detected and show in the menu.)
3. in the receipt it automatically plugged in my email, in the content  it has the user's android version number, stuff like that, and a screenshot, and a log.

I dont want to spend money to any third-party libraries. I would like to use a free one or develop the feature on my own. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [Instabug](https://instabug.com). It is a bug reporting SDK that you drop into your app and allows for the following:
Users can shake the phone while inside your app to report a bug.
Instabug menu will appear as the following

[image]

Interface is plain simple, suitable for non-tech users.

The bug reporting feature is free and unlimited. It is Incredibly easy to track your bugs through the product’s dashboard.

You could make use of the in-app chat feature which lets you reply back to your users within your app. (not free)

It only takes a line of code to integrate into your app.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) for that purpose, they support both Android and iOS platforms and fulfill all the needs you mentioned above. Apart from that and for the same price (it's free!), they include in the report some very valuable metadata like:

- OS version
- Device
- Proximity sensor
- Battery status
- Charge in progress
- Jailbreak/rooting status
- Device orientation
- Wi-Fi network
- Running processes
- etc

No need to do extra implementations, all is done!